# Fitting subView to View Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I fit a subView to the Proper Dimensions of the view I have Created in the story board?

For example

```
self.popUpView.addSubview(chart)
```

is presenting my display that i would like to span over the view I have in the story board.

[image]

```
class PopVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var popUpView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let chart = Chart(frame: self.popUpView.frame)


        let data = [(x: 0.0, y: 0), (x: 3, y: 2.5), (x: 4, y: 2), (x: 5, y: 2.3), (x: 7, y: 3), (x: 8, y: 2.2), (x: 9, y: 2.5)]

        let series = ChartSeries(data: data)

        series.area = true
        chart.xLabels = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24]
        chart.xLabelsFormatter = { String(Int(round($1))) + "h" }
        chart.add(series)


        //Circle Edge on barChartView
        popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
         popUpView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.popUpView.addSubview(chart)


    }

    @IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



}//END CLASS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really posted what isn't working about your solution, but the immediate thing I notice is that you're setting the `frame` of your `Chart` to `popUpView.frame`, when you should set it to `popUpView.bounds`.  This will ensure the origin of `Chart` is the origin of `popUpView` within `popUpView`'s coordinate system.

So, to show the example, change your initialization code to this:

```
let chart = Chart(frame: self.popUpView.bounds)
```

If you want to create a rect that makes the chart the same size as `popUpView`, but 20pt from the bottom (for example) you could say:

```
let chart = Chart(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.popUpView.bounds.size.width, height: self.popUpView.bounds.size.height - 20))
```

Maybe you want it to be half the height of `popUpView`:

```
let chart = Chart(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.popUpView.bounds.size.width, height: self.popUpView.bounds.size.height / 2))
```

Etc.

Comment: how should i resize the boundes say make it shorter in the view bounds

Comment: If you don't want it to be the EXACT same size and placement as `popUpView` you will need to set the frame to a `CGRect` where you specify the exact origin coordinates, the height, and the width.  Check Apple's docs on the `frame` of a UIView.

Comment: Whats the best way to be accurate with CRect without typing in random values?

Comment: It depends on what you want.  Maybe you want it to be a percentage of the `popUpView`, or a fixed height, like 20pt shorter than the `popUpView`.  I'll add those examples.

Comment: When creating a CGRect, the x/y values are for the upper left corner.  x:0, y:0 will put the upper left corner at the same spot as the upper left corner of `popUpView`.  Height/width are obvious.

Comment: Thank you for all your help